# is there a way to specify the type of a new column in a pandas dataframe as I am creating it using DataFrame.at?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I've got a pandas dataframe with some data in it. If I add a new column by specifying one in a `df.at[index, 'new_column']` call, the assigned dtype is arbitrarily object or float even when the assigned value is clearly something else like a string.

Is there a way to setup the type correctly from the start or do I just have to call `df.astype()` subsequent to the `df.at[]`

Comment: `df.at[index, 'new_column']` will populate a single _cell_ in the DataFrame. All other indices in the new column will be "missing" which is represented as `NaN` in `pandas`. Hence the float dtype for numerics since it needs to be to be a dtype which is compatible with `NaN` values. `string` columns are `object` by default in `pandas` unless using the [experimental string dtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.3/reference/api/pandas.StringDtype.html#pandas.StringDtype)

Comment: So if I want the new column to be string, what is the best way to write and code that. And I note that even if I do df['new_column'] = '', this still results in object type

Comment: I don't understand. You're populating a single cell in an entire column, you've not outlined how you want to handle all the missing values this generates.

Comment: A string type can handle NA. So, can be it setup as string dtype from the outset?

Comment: You might be able to do setting with expansion by building a Series `df['new_col'] = pd.Series(['value'], index=[index], dtype='string')`